# Blazor Server blank page on reload when rendering page from Razor Library

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Blazor application and would like to have a separate Razor library for shared screens and components so these can also be consumed by a .NET Maui app.

I have added the assembly to the router `AdditionalAssemblies` and I can navigate from the index page to the page in question, let's say Page 1.

However, when I refresh the page I get a blank screen. Nothing in the console (web or IDE) or browser inspector, apart from the `<pre>` tags.

If I move the page into the Web project it works fine and I am able to refresh it. Seems a bit weird that it's acting strangely using a Razor class library.

Web project has been setup with:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
                .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
   .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
```

Comment: It would help to post your entire `app.config` file, also have you tried commenting out the `AddInteractiveServerComponents` line?

Comment: What does `App.razor` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh you are pre-rendering.  The pre-render Razor `HttpRequest` context needs to know about the assembly as well.

```cs
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(new[] { typeof(Library.xxx).Assembly});
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, I wasn't able to find this answer using the docs :)

Comment: There isn't a wealth of knowledge yet around Blazor Render Modes.  I'm trying to put together a set of resources at the moment, but it's a rather complex topic!